# Eclipse e4 - adding a Core Expression

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

Hello I'd like to add a Core Expression to an HandledMenuItem.
I simply want to show that menu entry only if a selected MPart is active.

my implementation as follows:

```
<extension
     id="*"
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
       <definition
          id="com.project.test.definition1">
            <with
              variable="activePartId">
                <equals
                      value="com.project.test.part.time">
                </equals>
             </with>
          </definition>
       </extension>
```

It doesn't work. Is there any way to check which value activePartId has? Anyway it should be the right one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the `IServiceConstants` interface the variable name for the active e4 part is `e4ActivePart`.

However this does not make the part id available, so I think you may have to use the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point to define a property tester to test the id of the part. Something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
        class="package.TestPropertyTester"
        id="test.id"
        namespace="name.space"
        properties="partId"
        type="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.MUIElement"/>
```

```java
public class TestPropertyTester extends PropertyTester
{
  @Override
  public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object [] args, final Object expectedValue)
  {
    if (receiver instanceof MUIElement)
     {
       MUIElement element = (MUIElement)receiver;

       return element.getElementId().equals(expectedValue);
     }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```xml
   <definition
      id="com.project.test.definition1">
        <with
          variable="e4ActivePart">
            <test 
               property="name.space.partId"
               value="com.project.test.part.time">
             </test>
         </with>
      </definition>
```

There might be a simpler way but I have yet to find it!

Comment: does it contain the Part ID?

Comment: Greg, I need to know wheither a MPart of my Perspective is Active or not. I'd like to use core expressions.

Comment: The tester is not triggered if the definition is attached to a toolbar item (probably due to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400217)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need a seperate property tester for my core expression to work on menu items:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
  <definition
        id="com.example.definitions.initialperspective">
     <with
           variable="e4ActivePart">
        <not>
           <equals
                 value="com.example.perspectives.initial">
           </equals>
        </not>
     </with>
  </definition>
```

But the expression only worked on a menu item, not on a menu. So it worked on `File` > `Save` but not on `File` itself. Tested using Eclipse Kepler (4.3)

Comment: Here with Neon too, it seems like the core expressions work only for menu items, not toolbar items. ?

Comment: There is a bug involing toolbar items: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400217 (ref: https://jonathanjwright.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/eclipse-4-4-0-perspective-based-show-hide-of-tool-bar-items/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution may be to just declare the handler for this command in the handlers collection of the part (instead of the global handlers collection). In this case e4 will enable or disable the handled menu item according to whether your part is active or not. I don't know about visibility, though.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, related to this issue I figured out that there was a bug preventing the use of core expressions (391430). Then I found a workaround, maybe not really elegant, but it does a great job! In meantime I suppose the bug has been fixed by the way.

```
public boolean bugWA391430(String VarID, MApplication application)     {                                                
    String value = getAppContext(application, VarID); // get
    // the
    // Context Variable Value

    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        return true; // if value is empty the MPart is Open
    } else
        return false; // otherwise it's close

}
```